# How to get guaranteed unique list shuffles in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have a list of nine numbers (1-9), that I need to shuffle based on a seed, and guarantee that each permutation of that shuffle is unique.  I'd like to do that like this:

`list.shuffle(Random(seed))`

There are 9! (362,880) possible permutations of this list, and I know that if I pass it the same Random seed twice, those two permutations will be identical, but I need a way to guarantee that for any given seed between 0 and 362,880, the list order will be unique from any other seed in that range.

Is this possible in Kotlin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really a question about Kotlin, but algorithms in general.

There could be much better solution, but you can represent your seed as a number with variable base. First digit has base of 9, second has base of 8 and so on. When dealing with numbers of base 10, we need to repeatedly divide it by 10 and note the remainder to split it into digits. In our case we need to divide it by 9, 8, 7 and so on. This way we will convert the seed to a list of 9 digits like this: 0-8, 0-7, 0-6, ... . What is important: each seed has a unique list of such digits.

Now, if we create another list of numbers 1-9, then we can use the list of digits from the previous paragraph to pick numbers from it, removing them at the same time. Initially, we have 9 items in our list, so valid indexes are 0-8 and this is exactly the range of our first digit. Then we have only 8 remaining items, so they have indexes 0-7 and this is exactly what the second digit is. And so on.

This is not that easy to explain in words, code could be better:

```
fun shuffled1to9(seed: Int): List<Int> {
    require(seed in 0 until 362880)

    val remaining = (1..9).toMutableList()
    val result = mutableListOf<Int>()
    var curr = seed
    (9 downTo 2).forEach {
        val (next, pick) = curr divmod it
        result += remaining.removeAt(pick)
        curr = next
    }
    result += remaining.single()
    return result
}

infix fun Int.divmod(divisor: Int): Pair<Int, Int> {
    val quotient = this / divisor
    return quotient to (this - quotient * divisor)
}
```

`shuffled1to9(0)` returns original order of `1..9`. `shuffled1to9(362879)` returns the order inverted: `9..1`. Any number in between should generate a unique ordering.

Of course, it can be very easily generalized to different lists of numbers and to different sizes.

Comment: I just happen to be using Kotlin, but this could definitely apply to any language.  This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!